# My PHP page not retrieving anything from the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set up PHP and mySQL on a virtual machine on Amazon. I tried follow these instructions, and got no error messages. Everything seemed to work fine. I made a test PHP file, and it worked like a charm. Then I tried to retrieve something from my newly set up database… And I get a blank page.

```
<?php
$conn =  new mysqli('localhost', '[DB NAME]_user', '[USER PASSWORD]', '[DB NAME]', '');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT message FROM test;");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['message'];
?>
```

Any ideas on what I could do to check where it goes wrong? Anything I should check in the terminal to see if the database is really returning any values?

Any help is appreciated.

***ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:***

I tried Kęstutis's suggestion.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '[USER]', '[USER PASSWORD]', '[DB NAME]');
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
die($conn->connect_error);
}

if (!($result = $conn->query("SELECT message FROM test"))) {
die($conn->error);
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
print_r($row['message']);
}
```

It returned the string from $row['message']. No error messages.

Then I saw that

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '[USER]', '[USER PASSWORD]', '[DB NAME]');
```

is not the same as my initial

```
$conn =  new mysqli('localhost', '[DB NAME]_user', '[USER PASSWORD]', '[DB NAME]', '');
```

So I changed the row to my initial one with the '' in the end. And now I get an error message:

**Warning: mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5 Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/index.php on line 10 Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11**

Why?

Comment: are you sure your database has data in it?

Comment: You could try to do numerous things to get some type of error messages, i.e.: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`
and last but not least try
`echo $conn->error;`
to check if mysql shows you any message or you simply have problems with your mysql

Comment: Because that parameter is essentially a MySQL port and if left blank it is replaced by the default (usually 3306) so either use 3306 (or whatever your mysql port is) or leave it as blank. Just remember '' is not the same as null/blank and what you're doing is effectively trying to explicitly set it to '' which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '[USER]', '[USER PASSWORD]', '[DB NAME]');
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    die($conn->connect_error);
}

if (!($result = $conn->query("SELECT message FROM test"))) {
    die($conn->error);
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row['message']);
}
```

this way you should see at what point it fails if it fails at all

Comment: With this code, it does return the value from ($row['message']). No error messages, just the string I put there which happens to be "Bajskorv!". So now I wonder why the initial php code gave me a blank screen? (See initial post for details). Thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

check for errors in connection:

```
 $conn =  new mysqli('localhost', '[DB NAME]_user', '[USER PASSWORD]', '[DB NAME]', '');
 if (!$conn) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
```

try select db:

```
 $conn->select_db("database_name");
```

Comment: he selects the db in the MySQLi constructor so it is not necessary to check it for a second time